# ¿Está permitido usar el símbolo de dos puntos dos veces en una frase?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación

A veces me ha pasado que estoy redactando un texto, y me encuentro en la tesitura de querer poner dos veces el símbolo de "dos puntos" (:) en una frase. Por poner un ejemplo (recién inventado):

> Y así llegamos a la solución: vaciar la lista de elementos temporales antes de continuar con el algoritmo, tal y como se muestra en el siguiente ejemplo:
>
> [Ejemplo]

Cuando me salen este tipo de construcciones, siempre acabo reordenando la frase y escribiéndola de forma que no me aparezca dos veces el símbolo de dos puntos en la misma frase, ya que se me hace raro que no aparezca un punto en medio de ambos, y la pondría tal que así:

> Llegamos así a la solución, que consistiría en vaciar la lista...

El caso es que no sé si este tipo de construcciones están permitidas, si hay alguna regla que impida poner dos veces los dos puntos en una frase, si se permite, si se desaconseja, si estoy siendo víctima de un TOC, etc. ¿Dice algo la RAE al respecto?

Comment: Qué curioso, el otro día también tuve esta duda. Yo creo que sí es correcto, el [DPD en *dos puntos*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=2a3yRXFBiD6rvDOMtq) no dice lo contrario. En particular, me quedo con _1.7 Sirven para marcar una pausa enfática tras locuciones de carácter introductorio (...)  En la mayoría de estos casos los dos puntos son sustituibles por la coma_ y la coma no tiene límites.

Comment: @fedorqui A ver, cualquier otro símbolo de puntuación se puede escribir todas las veces que quieras, pero no sé por qué tiendo a hacer esta distinción con los dos puntos. Es cierto que al menos el DPD no dice que no se pueda usar todas las veces que quieras, pero las frases con más de una aparición de los dos puntos me acaban pareciendo extrañas, de ahí la pregunta.

Comment: Sí, a mí también. Recuerdo artículos de Eduardo Haro Tecglen que usaban mucho esta técnica y que siempre leía con cierto escepticismo ortográfico, hasta que me acostumbré. Supongo que la clave está en distinguir el uso que representan en cada caso, pues muchos de los puntos que describe la DPD solo se usarían una sola vez en una frase.

Comment: Muy buena pregunta (me pasa a menudo) y muy enriquecedoras respuestas. Hasta ahora he venido resolviendo el problema usando que "se usa punto y coma para separar subordinadas explicativas". Tendré en cuenta todo lo de este hilo, gracias.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La pregunta era si la RAE decía algo al respecto sobre el uso repetido de los dos puntos en una frase. [Copio a continuación](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=QnXogrDATdkAkhJv) de la *Ortografía 2010*:

> Dificulta asimismo la percepción de las relaciones entre las unidades lingüísticas, y debe, por ello, evitarse, el uso repetido de los dos puntos en un mismo enunciado [...]
>
> Se recomienda en estos casos buscar soluciones que eviten la repetición, como el empleo de otro signo de puntuación en lugar de los dos puntos [...] o la modificación de la redacción [...].

Por tanto sí, se debe evitar la redacción del ejemplo planteado en la pregunta. Otra cosa es cuando la repetición se debe a que cada aparición de los dos puntos está en un discurso diferente. Expone la RAE el siguiente ejemplo:

> Wallace lo cuenta en su autobiografía: "Me planteé una pregunta: ¿Por qué unos mueren y otros sobreviven?"

En estos contextos la repetición no dificulta la percepción de las dependencias sintácticas entre los constituyentes del enunciado, y son por tanto admisibles.

Answer (score 4):

Si nos ceñimos a la definición de los "dos puntos" de la [Wikipedia](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dos_puntos).

Yo me aventuraría a decir que **está permitido, porque no lo prohíbe**.

No obstante, si los dos puntos se emplean para desarrollar un tema ya presentado:

> *Detienen el discurso para llamar la atención sobre lo que sigue, que
>   siempre está en estrecha relación con el texto precedente*
>
> -*Wikipedia*-

Usando "los dos puntos", uno a continuación de otro, sin concluir de manera clara los que anteceden, corremos el riesgo de conseguir todo lo contrario de lo que se propone. En lugar de llamar la atención, la perdemos.

Tomando el ejemplo de Carlos:

> Y así llegamos a la solución: **vaciar la lista de elementos temporales
>   antes de continuar con el algoritmo**, tal y como se muestra en el
>   siguiente ejemplo:
>
> [**Ejemplo**]

Aquí los últimos dos puntos (en mi opinión) aplastan todo el esfuerzo de los primeros dos puntos. Es decir el *Ejemplo* es la información que prevalece sobre todo el resto. Incluso sobre `vaciar la lista...`.

Para no boicotear nuestro propio discurso, si nos encontramos en la situación propuesta por @Carlos, lo mejor que podemos hacer es reconducir el discurso:

> Y así llegamos a la solución: **vaciar la lista de elementos temporales
>   antes de continuar con el algoritmo.**
>
> Ejemplo:
>
> [**Ejemplo**]

El *tal y como se muestra...* creo que es redundante al *Ejemplo*. Ya sabemos que el ejemplo muestra y que es un ejemplo del punto anterior.

Eliminamos ruido y usando el "."  conseguimos que se asimile la información anterior y se centre en el siguiente bloque con esa información aún en mente.

Marcamos un *tempo* que antes se hacía difícil de seguir. No avasallamos al lector con demasiada "información importante" de golpe.